# How to write a callback function in c++, where I have third party API which returns me the status of the task(which is being running on its own thread

Tags: c++

I have a third party API method which will send the request to server asynchronously from the secondary thread. There are few API methods in the third party tool to check the progress of the task which was sent in to server, but since I send the input asychronusly, I need a to create a callback function and pass it as a function pointer to the third party API's so that if the response comes back from the server, the data will be sent to my function return.

Can you assist me on how to implement this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What part are you struggling with?

Comment: A third party library such as what? A task such as what? An API such as what?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a [`std::promise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise) as context for the callback. The corresponding future allows you to wait for the result to be available:

```
class ThirdParty
{
    std::thread m_thread;

    static void BackgoundWorker(void(*f)(std::string, void*), void* context)
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
        f("Async result", context);
    }
public:
    ~ThirdParty()
    {
        if (m_thread.joinable())
        {
            m_thread.join();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Asynchronously runs logic calling the callback after 2 seconds
     */
    void Run(void(*f)(std::string, void*), void* context)
    {
        assert(!m_thread.joinable());
        m_thread = std::thread(&BackgoundWorker, f, context);
    }
};

void Callback(std::string asyncMessage, void* context)
{
    auto const promise = static_cast<std::promise<std::string>*>(context);
    promise->set_value(std::move(asyncMessage));
}

std::string CallThirdPartyFunction(ThirdParty& thirdParty)
{
    std::promise<std::string> promise;
    thirdParty.Run(&Callback, &promise);
    std::cout << "third party logic running\n"; // just some output to indicate the asynchronous task is running
    return promise.get_future().get(); // wait until the result is available and return that result
}

int main()
{
    ThirdParty tp;
    std::cout << CallThirdPartyFunction(tp) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```